# Here is the link of a non verbal pattern sequencing question.can anyone help me with that?

Tags: pattern, visual

This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1961837/376925) has an another non verbal sequencing/IQ-test question. I want to know which among the given option comes next after picture E.

For clear angle of the pic.

[image]

Comment: 1. Please post the image in the question (the right way around!).  2. Quote the source, as you obviously did not create this. 3. None of the tags are correct. Edit: I corrected the tags.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it :) ya I edited the picture. And I took this problem from my class room nodule and nowhere I mentioned that it was created by me :) will appreciate your help in getting it's solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say

> 1

Because (as noted by Kruga in your previous question):

> The number of pieces alternating each step follows a special rule, this time it is 1-2-3-1(-2-3 etc, as I suppose).
>  And pieces are flipping in the counter-clockwise order: the topmost in step A-B, two left pieces in step B-C, two right and top in C-D, left in D-E. So we flip two lower pieces and get the position 1.